# Connect Monitors to PC Wirelessly?

Tags: mac, display, multiple-monitors, external-display

I'm trying to put together a quick setup guide and equipment list for what someone will need to do if they want to hook up multiple monitors to a single laptop wirelessly for additional real estate in a works space.

Now I'm still figuring out all the things I'm going to need. Would appreciate any help with someone who has setup something like this or interested in doing something like it. The reason to make a quick start up guide is simply because I'm making a small studio for myself to work on my digital art. And in this studio I would like to to be able to connect to all the monitors I hook up around, easily through my laptop.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you okay with them being laggy, having a low frame rate, having compression artifacts, or having low resolution? Modern display resolutions and frame rates require very high bandwidth; higher than what any wireless technology provides.